# Is there a way to move a UI element to a particular point instead of using CGAffine(translate: ) to move them by a particular amount?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the need to make a `UIImage` move from the center of the screen to the center of the top of the screen. However, `CGAffine(translate:)` allows you to move **by** a certain distance as opposed to **to** a certain location.

Can this be managed?

Edit: Apologies, should've had more details:

So here is the current position of my UIView:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    containerOne.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    containerOne.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    containerOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    containerOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
)]
```

and here is where I'd like for it to end up:

```
containerOne.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
containerOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
containerOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
containerOne.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
```

While I have tried using .frame as suggested below, I am still wondering if there is a way to have the UIView shift from one constraint to another the same way CGAffine translate works. Please do let me know if I can add more details or code to my question!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I know you have tested some codes before without luck, please post the codes you tried and follow the guidelines of the SO about [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using autolayout. So you if you need to update constraint with another constraint, you need to take a reference to old an new constraints. Then you just need to apply it and call `.layoutIfNeeded()` on the container view.

Like this:

```
let old = containerOne.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
old.isActive = true
```

And later:

```
let new = containerOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
old.isActive = false
new.isActive = true

view.layoutIfNeeded() // Should be the owner of the subviews
```

**Note that** you can put `.layoutIfNeeded()` inside an animation block to make it animate.

---

#### Before clarifying the question

Each view has a property called `frame` and it's a `CGRect` that have a property called `origin`. You cam change the origin to anything you need to make it move there.

```
view.frame.origin.x = 100
view.frame.origin.y = 100
```

or both at once:

```
view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
```

remember `origin` refers to top left point of the view, you can use `center` instead.

<sub>There are other options but these are simplest options</sub>

Comment: I have edited my question to be more coherent, thanks for the suggestions!